# Emacs + moc (console audio player)

Tags: emacs

I listen music through [moc](http://moc.daper.net/) (console audio player), I want manage of moc through emacs.
Is there a script for emacs lets you do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [EMMS](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/EMMS), I haven't used it in a very long time.  The last time I used, it can use any player such as mplayer, mpg123/mpg321 to play music.  It was able to make playlists as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Bongo](https://github.com/dbrock/bongo) which you can download from melpa